# How to prove A is a flat R-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, ideals, tensor-products, flatness

Let A be a right R-module. Suppose for every  left ideal J of R, the homomorphism $f:A\otimes J\to A$ defined by $f(x\otimes y)=xy$ is injective, then A is a flat R-module.(the identity 1 is in R)

I found the result in my book but didn't give me the proof, and I felt very confused about it! Can someone tell me how to prove it?

Comment: Does this theorem assume that $1 \in R$? Because if so, then $f$ is just the inclusion $J \to R$ tensored by $A$. That feels like it would be important in a proof, and it shows why the given condition is even related to flatness as defined by "the functor $A\otimes -$ preserves exactness".

Comment: Yes, the identity 1 is in R,

Comment: In addition to the linked duplicate, also see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348745/question-on-criterion-for-flat-modules?rq=1) or [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/398907/29335) that showed up when you used the search feature for your question. You **did** use the search feature before posting your question, right?